# Making calls and passing values to a vbscript from a ruby script

Tags: ruby, vbscript

Is it possible to call a vbscript from a ruby script? Bascially, I am creating a temp folder with a random name in my ruby script and I would like to call the vbscript and pass the name of this folder to carry out the next action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling the Windows Scripting Host (`cscript`) with your script:

```
 system "cscript //nologo script.vbs #{random_filename}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use system and pass it as a command-line arg

```
system "script.vbs #{random_filename}"
```

Comment: Thanks...I tried it but does not work. Any idea why it would not work?

Comment: These two commands work but the call to vbscript does not work . I even tried using a vbscript name that does not exist hoping it would throw and error but it seems the calls to vbs are ignored.
system "echo Hello"

system "dir"

Comment: As stated below you need to probably pass it to the Windows Scripting Host. so add cscript to the above.